# django form resubmitted upon refresh pag

Tags: django, django-views

After I submit the form for the first time and then refresh the form it gets resubmitted and and I don't want that.
How can I fix this ?

Here are my views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from free.models import contact

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
    
        en = contact(fullname=fullname, email=email, message=message)
        en.save()
    
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the browser, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        contact.objects.create(fullname=fullname, email=email, message=message)
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`contact`</s> to `Contact`.